# xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getchildren' and relative XPath does not find attributes

Tags: python, api

I am not able parse and print elements and attributes from a collection category from web page using atom-xml. From the Python script below, the "print(response.content)" lists contents ok and includes:
'''

```
"xmlns= <atom:category scheme="http://www.zooo.com/types" 
term="changetimber/has-game"/>
```

'''
And prints child tags ok:
'''

```
{http://www.w3.org/2007/app}workspace
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title
{http://www.w3.org/2007/app}collection
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}title
{http://www.w3.org/2007/app}categories
{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}category
```

'''

After the Python script py is ran, get error
'''
children = hasgame.getchildren
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute
'getchildren'
'''

And does not print anything from the for condition below:
'''
for category in root.findall('''.//@term="changetimber/hasgame" ] '''):
print(category.attrib)
'''

The Python script below is:
'''

```
    import requests
    from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
    url = 'http://ipaddress/mygame'
    response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user','pass'))
    print(response)
    print("***********list response content ******************")
    print(response.content)
    print("******** Display child tags********")
    root = ET.fromstring(response.content)
    for child in root.iter('*'):
    print(child.tag)
    # Create a dictionary
    xmlDictionary = {}
    for hasgame in root:
    children = hasgame.getchildren()
    xmlDictionary[children[0].text] = children[1].text

    print("******** print dictionary ******")
    print(xmlDictionary)
    for category in root.findall('''.//@term="changetimber/hasgame" ] '''):
       print(category.attrib)
```

'''

Answer (score 14):

Change `hasgame.getchildren()` into `list(hasgame)`

Comment: Hi @nasiajai. I used "hasname" as an example. The actual atom xml page contains"has-game", with hyphen. When I used "has-game" in the for condition, and run the .py script, get this error: `SyntaxError: cannot assign to expression`. To try to fix, I created a variable as hasgame = "has-game". Then, use "hasgame" in the for condition. Next, I ran the .py script again. But get errors `IndexError: list index out of range` for my statement: xmlDictionary[children[0].text] = children[1].text in the script. Thank you.

Comment: Just to add a little more info about the reason here: xml.etree.ElementTree.Element used to have a method called getchildren(), so you'll see existing code that uses it. It was deprecated in version version 3.2 and then removed in 3.9 (see https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.getchildren)

Comment: Hi, it don't really work the same way, the children being sometime XML element it will alway display a one element list

Comment: Hi @asiajai, SklwekFr thank you for the inputs. I agree with both of your answers. It was challenging situation and I was not able to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can change Change `hasgame.getchildren()` into `hasgame.iter()` and then modify accordingly